# Print additional fields in wp_new_user_notification_email_admin

Tags: hooks

I have added a new field in user registration form of a Wordpress website using below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'twooc_extra_register_fields' );
function twooc_extra_register_fields() { 

?>
     
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
       <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Mobile Num *', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
       </p>
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <?php
}
```

Now I want to print **Mobile Number** inside the email that goes to the site admin using **wp_new_user_notification_email_admin**. Is there any way to print any additional fields to this email ?

Please note that this email is sent to the admin **after** the user clicks on the confirmation code sent to his email. Something like below:

*Please activate your account via this link - https://www.example.com/user-account-3/?user_token=66d584853871730d5df125d6c895508a*

Thanks

Comment: You already found the correct filter, what is stopping you exactly from manipulating the `$wp_new_user_notification_email_admin['message']`?

Comment: I want to fetch the mobile number field from the DB and print in this filter for the admin. But I cannot find any variable for that.